# How to pass input value from one form to another form at same jsp page?

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

I have two **forms** in my jsp page, first form have input values and second form have submit button,
i can't use both in same form because of some issue. now i want to access **first form** value into **second form**.

My Sample Code is Here,

```
<form name="onchange" id="first">
<div><input type="text" name="n1"></div>
<select onchange="document.forms['onchange'].submit();" name="select">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
</form>

<form action="servlet" id="second">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I need to access a first form value to second form on **submit.** is it any way to access? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont exactly know what you want to do.But you cant send data of one form using a submit button of another form.

You could do one thing either use sessions or use hidden fields that has the submit button.
You could use javascript/jquery to pass the values from the first form to the hidden fields of the second form.Then you could submit the form.

Or else the easiest you could do is use sessions.

**IN Jquery**

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[firstname]" id="elm_6">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[lastname]" id="elm_7">
    </form>

    <form action="#">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[b_firstname]" id="elm_14">
<input type="text" class="input-text " value="" size="32" name="user_data[s_firstname]" id="elm_16">

<input type="submit" value="Continue" name="dispatch[checkout.update_steps]">
    </form>


$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    $('#elm_14').val($('#elm_6').val());
    $('#elm_16').val($('#elm_7').val());
});
```

This is the jsfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/FPsdy/102/

Comment: i have updated.refer to the code.This should help you..plz reply so that i knowu got it..

Comment: i want to enter input values only in first form not in second form and no need any extra input box in form 2. i need only the value of form 1 to form 2. i tryed ur sample code, it returns empty value when i click Continue. i used <% a=request.getParameter("user_data[firstname]") %>in form 2. it returns nothing.

Comment: its just an example...in d 2nd form instead of input type=text ,put input type=hidden

Comment: how can transfer data in java script after submit. pls update ur code to java script.